# bash extended globs :: rm all *.jpg files except two particular ones

Tags: bash

Can I use Bash extended glob patterns to implement logical 'AND' ? Say I have a folder of **jpg** files (among others) and I want to rm all *jpg* files except **A.jpg** and **B.jpg**. How would I do that without trying tricks like remaming the files temporarily and so on ? I guess the general theme is how one can combine logical expressions and negations in Bash extended globs.

Comment: Unless this is to be done several times, why not just move the files you want to save to a temporary directory, and then move them back when you're done?

Comment: it's going into a Makefile and I would rather avoid moving files in Makefiles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(A|B).jpg
```

`!(pattern-list)`   Matches anything except one of the given patterns.
`pattern-list` is a list of one or more patterns separated by a `‘|’`

---

You can also use `find`:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' ! -name '[AB].jpg' -delete
```

Comment: Thanks but there may be other kinds of files as well in the folder, i.e. not just jpgs (I've edited my original question to make it explicit).

Comment: In that case, `rm !(A|B).jpg`

Comment: @glennjackman Nice!